# Dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows 11 Pro

Tags: ubuntu, windows-11

What I want to have:

- a PC running *Windows 10*
- a Laptop (Lenovo) running *Windows 11 Pro*
- a bootable **external** SSD with *Ubuntu* on it, which runs on my PC *(Win10)* and my laptop *(Win11)*. Do you say bootable? I like to call it my portable OS c:

My Laptop *Win11* is using BitLocker (which is good, I want that, there is important data on it).

Here is what I did:

- I had my PC *(Win10)*, Laptop *(Win11)* encrypted with BitLocker, an empty USB and an empty SDD.
- I flashed Ubuntu iso onto the USB using my PC and installed it on the external SDD.
- When I boot my PC and spam `F11` *(boot menu)* I can choose the SSD and get into my Linux System as I want it to.
- But when I do it on my Laptop, spam `F12` *(boot menu)* choose the SSD, it shows me the BitLocker login screen *(not the recovery screen)*. I type in my password and get to the *Windows 11* login screen, not the Ubuntu System I wanted.

Questions:

- Why does my approach not work?
- What am I looking for? I have looked into TPM but I'm not sure if that is what Im looking for. I would be okay for me to use BitLocker on the external SDD as well, but I would still like to be able to use it on my Win10 (Home) wich has no BitLocker (idm typing in the password if that would still work in Win10).
- Other Workaround I could be using to achieve my desired set-up? (Being able to have Linux on external SSD and use it on Win10 and Win11 (with BitLocker active).

-> Im not saying, I dont wanna disable BitLocker at all, if its just temporarly to make a set-up and reactivate it after (or using suspend) that should be fine as well.

For the boot menus, I've read a bunch of people are using a grub screen. I'm sorry this is not my expertise, how do I know which boot menu I'm using, and is it relevant for you?
I think both my PC and my Laptop use UEFI.

Comment: Not sure, that's why this is a comment not an answer, but I think Secure Boot is required for Windows 11 and that it is the cause for things breaking when it comes to linux.

Comment: @LPChip Thanks for the answer. I havent considered my set-up 'broken'. As both my PC and Laptop work just fine. Also I can use Ubuntu on the PC. But not on the Laptop due to BitLocker (probably)

Comment: Do you have Secure Boot enabled on your PC? For your laptop it will be required, and my point is that I'm fairly sure that secure boot on causes issues with linux.

Comment: LPChip, Ubuntu, and probably most other recent distros, can be installed and boot with Secure Boot enabled. There are a number of dual-boot Windows 10/Ubuntu PC's I regularly use with Secure Boot. However, *Windows Fast Startup and BIOS Quick Boot*  do cause issues when dual booting -- disable those features.

Comment: Any configuration change will require the BitLocker recovery key, every single time, you change the boot order of your device.  You really should look at WSL or a VM if you want to use BitLocker and still run Linux.  Secure Boot isn't the problem, it's BitLocker, changing the boot order will is considered a configuration changes and will result in the requirement of the recovery key every single time.

Comment: If you select the SSD in the temporary UEFI boot menu but end up in Windows, then something went wrong with the Linux boot. I don't know if this was caused by a SecureBoot problem (in that case I would have expected a security error and an aborted boot) or another general Linux bootloader problem. I would suspect the latter so Linux may not boot even if the system would be free of Bitlocker and Windows. How is the SSD connected to your laptop? Is the Linux version new enough to support the laptop hardware?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! 

@DrMoishePippik Sounds good, How do I disable those features? With those disabled. could I end up in the infinity loop which Ramhound is describing? Considering it as a configuration change.

Comment: @Ramhound I really dont care about the boot order, IDM choosing the option myself everytime I turn on the pc/laptop. I think you are describing the infinity loop problem I've read somewhere here in superuser, would really love not to find out the hard way.

Comment: @Robert I dont think there is aproblem with the Linux-boot, it boots perfectly fine on my PC and runs as I am writing this.

Comment: Update: 
I've turned off the *Windows Fast Startup*. Retried, and still got to the BitLocker Screen and afterwards to Windows login. 
I cant manage to disable the BIOS Quick Boot, as that would require the BIOS Password, which I do not have (I got the Laptop gifted, and the password was already set, back than). I dont want wanna go though all the trouble reinstalling windows or w/e to give this a try. Tho I did try to remove the battery to reset the CMOS, so the password would vanish, but unfortunaly I do not own ultra-mini (six-crossed?) screw driver to loosen the screws. *sadface* :c

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I think we are onto something. I have disabled BitLocker, just for the sake of making sure, the Linux is working without it. But it didnt, it still booted windows. So I think its either as you say with the *BIOS Quick Start* or another guess could be, that booting from USB is disabled (even tho its a SSD, ik). Next week, Ill ask a friend to lend me his screwdriver xD Will update back, as soon as I know more. Thanks for the help so far, everyone!

Comment: @Robin You are booting from USB therefore every computer that has a different chipsets or USB controller have to be considered different. A boot method that works on the PC does not necessarily also work on the laptop. Especially new hardware released in the last two years is often badly supported by Linux that is my personal experience when it comes to booting Linux from USB.

Comment: “I think you are describing the infinity loop problem” - No; I am not describing an “infinite loop problem”

Comment: still trying to figure out whether or not, removing the cmos battery will remove the bios password or not. Some Articles say, it will, some state it will not. 
Also cant find, anything if I can try the bios password more then 3 times, if i restart the pc after 2 tries. 
Can also find nothing if cmospwd.exe would work on lenovo ideapad 5. 
And some other things. Basicly at a loss. Unless the person who I get the laptop from, will remember the password I'll drop the booting thing, sorry

Comment: person who gifted me to laptop, still knows the bios password. will report back as soon as we met again (can take a while)

Comment: got the bios password now. went in to the boot menu, changed boot order and it still doesnt work. It simply just boots up windows

Comment: @LPChip I have disabled secure boot (it was active) and I have also disabled bitlocker. My Laptop still boots into windows.